# What are the TCDBroker, TCDLink, and TCDWAI in Tridion 2013 SP1? I am getting event log errors on startup

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-delivery, broker

I am running Tridion 2013 SP1 on a VM that I have recently copied from a corrupt drive to a new drive.

When I start up the VM and go in to the Tridion CM, the UI is broken. The event viewer shows an error in the Tridion Content Manager log:

> The description for Event ID 100 from source TCDBroker cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Could not load Java runtime libraries at
>   the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table

This is duplicated for TCDBroker, TCDLink and TCDWAI.

I've searched for this message on the rest of the interwebs, but have not found anything helpful.

Any help diagnosing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

TCDBroker, TCDLink and TCDWAI are Windows services which serve Tridion Content Delivery capability to your web applications.

Your issue is probably got to do with that no valid JDK runtime is installed. Tridion 2013 requires a 32 and 64 bit JDK version 7 installed on your machine.